# Function (Riemann) integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f: [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. How to prove that $f$ is (Riemann) integrable?

Comment: Since [0,1] is a compact set then any continuous function $f$ in this set attain a minimum and maximum...

Comment: @user209663 I do not see the relation with my question, since in my case $f$ need not be continuous on $[0,1]$.

Comment: You are right. I misread the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't conclude that $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, because it doesn't have to be:
$$
f(x) = \cases{1 & if $x \in \{0, 1\}$\\0& otherwise}
$$
is convex, and not continuous.

On the other hand, you should be able to show by using the definition of Riemann integrability that (potential) discontinuity at two points doesn't stop a function from being integrable.

---

**Edit:** Boundedness

The function value on $(0,1/2)$ cannot at any point go below $\min(f(1/2),2f(1/2) - f(1))$, and the function value on $(1/2, 1)$ cannot at any point go below $\min(2f(1/2) - f(0))$, so the function is bounded below.

If the function ever has a value greater than $\max(f(1),f(2))$, then that violates convexity, so the function must be bounded above.

Comment: How do I know that $f$ is bounded? I believe this is needed.

Comment: @serial I added how to show boundedness.

Comment: For the first part you mean $[0,1/2]$ and $[1/2,1]$ right?

Comment: @serial Not really, but I did mess up some details. Also, the bounded above can be done much easier. Give me a few minutes, and I'll fix.

Comment: What I mean by "not really" is that I usually consider convexity to be about the function value at three distinct points. In this case, one of the points is $\frac12$, one of the points is either $0$ it $1$, and the third point is between them.